# jquery template loaded from distant server

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I am using jquery templates on several projects. Thing is, in order to get a consistent feel, I was planning to put all the common templates on a CDN server, and then load them from different services with (in head):

```
<script id="errorPage" src="http://www.mycdn.com/error-page.html" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"></script>
```

Then (in page ready handler), I use the following code to render my template:

```
$("#errorPage").tmpl("errorPage", {'message': 'Permission denied'}).prependTo("body");
```

Thing is ... it doesn't work !? nothing is rendered ... I don't know if it is even possible. I am very new to jquery-template, so I might also be missing something obvious !!!

Any idea ?

Comment: That's a good question.  I considered it for a couple minutes the other day, but I'm only using the template on one site so I put it in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does your template look like? Is browser processing it as html or as javascript? Try putting it in .js file or loading your templates as a string variables in javascript file. Instead of

```
<script id="errorPage" src="http://www.mycdn.com/error-page.html" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"></script>
```

load some .js file which has something like this:

```
var errorPage = "<html><body>error: ${message}</body></html>"; //replace with your template
...
$.template( "errorPage", errorPage);
```

You can have one or more js files with templates, but  should have javascript as a source, not html.

UPDATE after I tried your scenario:
When loaded the way how you tried, contents of error-page.html are not parsed as jquery template and you get empty errorPage variable.

Comment: Great !!! It works ... any idea why jquery-template doesn't like how I did it before ?

Comment: Well, I would say that browser when loads .html file ignores type attribute of script tag and does not perform parsing of js inside. I will check that now and update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the templates in external files and call them with `$.getScript`.

For instance:

**example.html**

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.js"></script> 
<script>
$(function() {
    $.getScript('./template.js', function(data) { 
        $.tmpl("message", { id:1, msg:"Some Message!" } ).appendTo('#output');
    });
});
</script>
<body>
<div id="output"></div>
</body>
```

**template.js**

```
$.template("message", '<a href="/message/${id}">${msg}</a>');
```

The only problem with testing this is that browsers don't usually allow file access for AJAX requests, so you'll have to throw it into a local web server to try it out.

edit:
You can apparently also force html-only requests:

```
$.get('./template2.js', function(data) { 
    $.template("message2", data);
    $.tmpl( "message2", { id:1, msg:"Some Message!" } ).appendTo('#output');
}, 'html');
```

**template2.js**

```
<p id="script2">
    <a href="/message/${id}">${msg}</a>
</p>
```

Notice how after the callback in `$.get`, I'm explicitly specifying 'html'.

Comment: I think that's not going to work because of [same-origin-policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), or will it ?

Comment: `$.getScript` appends a `script` tag after the page loads, so it is the same as adding `<script></script>` and is subject to the same rules there (which works).  Loading via `$.get` does require same origin.

Comment: You may be able to hack something together using `$.load`. e.g. load into a temporary/hidden div, then create a template from that innerHtml.  To me, the `$.getScript` method is cleanest.

Comment: Well ... I can try, but I think that getScript is ajax, and therefore cannot work, since it will request the templates from a different server ...